# How to extract time from string in pyspark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a string that contains time in the following pattern that I want to extract in pyspark

```
......&eventTime=2017-02-22T01%3a02%3a07.1816943Z&......
```

This is what I tried but didn't work; df_event.EventParameters is a column which contains the time.

```
df_localTime = pyspark.sql.functions \
          .regexp_extract(df_event.EventParameters, '.*(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}%3a\\d{2}%3a\\d{2}\\.\\{3}).*', 1) \
          .alias('localTime')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that prevents it from matching anything is this part `\.\{3}`

It basically says

```
\. match a literal dot  
\{ match a literal open brace  
3 match a literal three  
} match a literal close brace
```

I assume you meant there to be a `\d` instead.
`\.\d{3}`

So, the stringed regex is now `'.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}%3a\d{2}%3a\d{2}\.\d{3}).*'`

which now matches this (*group 1 is highlighted*)

......&eventTime=`2017-02-22T01%3a02%3a07.181`6943Z&......

Formatted (for readability)

```
 .* 
 (                             # (1 start)
      \d{4} - \d{2} - \d{2} 
      T 
      \d{2} %3a \d{2} %3a \d{2} 
      \. \d{3} 
 )                             # (1 end)
 .*
```